# How to Convert TextFrame into Image

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, office-interop, openxml-sdk

I have doubt in convert TextFrame into image, please help to do this in VSTO or OpenXmlSDK with/without third party library, if any one have idea, please share with me....

```
            Word.Shapes shapes = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Shapes;
            foreach (Word.Shape shape in shapes)
            {
                if (shape.TextFrame.HasText >= 1)
                {
//how to convert TextFrame into as a Image
                }
                else
                {
                    shape.Delete();
                }
            }
```

Thanks in Advance,
Saran

Comment: Do you want to convert the box into an image that'll be in the document or create a new image file?

Comment: Many many thank for quick reply, i want to convert box into image into same document and same position and delete existing TextFrame

Comment: what version of Word?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be

1. Get x,y coordinate of textbox in word doc (use vsto)
2. Save file to pdf or xps (use vsto)
3. Convert xps or pdf to image (use any free third party library)
4. Extract image image using x,y cordinate obtained in step 1. (Use
   GDI)